# Script Works in Terminal, but Not as .sh

Tags: bash, cron, shell-scripting

I have a script that works in the terminal perfectly, but for some reason won't fire off either in cron or when I run the script manually.

I don't know if it makes a difference, but it's running on an Asustor NAS device.

Here's the script

```
#!/bin/bash

tar cvf reachdata_$(date +'%Y_%m_%d').tar /volume1/reachdata
```

Comment: Try specifying the rull path to `tar` and `date` in the script. Have you given the script execute permissions?

Comment: Do you get anything in your cron logs?

Comment: Also try specifying the full path to the script in the crontab.  And the obligatory dumb question - does the script run from a command prompt? (ofc, as the user you have it setup in cron for)

Comment: NAS device uses a 'Linux-type' OS. That's why #!/bin/bash doesn't work - it doesn't exist. No fix still, but definitely found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it's on an nfs server, you might want to check if the `noexec` option is included in the mount-options. That will prevent scripts such as that from executing. Alternately, ensure the script is marked as executable.